# Add Ordinal/Consecutive Value for similar values in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

OK - I have a table with the following columns - what I need to do, is in instances where there is a same visit_no, I need to populate a int field with an ordinal number (priority) for each code - e.g. - so the "Priority" field is what I am looking to have populated - a new successive number for each "Code" value within the each similar "visit_no"

```
Visit_no    Code     Priority
123456      97110    1
445566      85025    1
445566      71402    2
445566      71020    3
789888      80053    1
789888      97110    2
111111      85025    1
```

Comment: I would not populate the source table with this - I would define a view that calculates it for you, otherwise it _will_ get out of sync at some point (like the first delete).  Is there an ID field or some other indicator of order?  Order of insertion is not a reliable method of ordering items.

Comment: how is priority defined? obviously not by ascending order of Code, as Visits 789888 and 445566 do not fulfil that. Is there another criteria?

Comment: I need to populate priority top down - for each "code" value - within each "group" of "visit_no" - so literally, it is like looping through the visit_nos and inserting an auto ID for each row - top to bottom. Top gets 1 and moves down from there. I figure I can do it with a cursor and this table will only be touched this once - but thought that row_number or something with a partition or something would be better

Comment: I think this may work: SELECT Row_Number() OVER (Partition BY visit_no ORDER BY code)

Comment: Just so you are aware, when you order by Code (which are not distinct values in this case), you are NOT going to get the results with the same ordering every time. If at all possible order by code and some other column(s) that will produce a consistent order.

Comment: A select without an order by is non deterministic.  Even if the table has a PK the order is non deterministic.

Answer (score 0):

Dense_Rank is a function which increments the rank only when the value your ordering on changes.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-ca/library/ms173825.aspx

```
Select Visit_no, Code, Priority = DENSE_RANK() OVER (Partition by Visit_No order by Code)
From YourTable
```